# replacing smd atmega328p on a arduino nano clone

Tags: arduino

I accidentally blown up the original chip. :embrassed

I have successfully soldered a new chip on but the MKII programmer won't enter programming mode. but I can clearly see  the characterisic not quite perfect square wave on my scope.

Am guessing it's because the chip hasn't been configured to use the external crystal.  Besides buying a new dev board/ removing the tiny crystal, is there an easy way I can get myself out of this mess?

Comment: There's really no reason to replace the chip on an Arduino. Just get a new board.

Comment: If you have a 2nd Arduino available maybe you can use it as an ISP (In-System-Programmer) and re-program your troublesome chip. There are plenty of tutorials to be found if you search the internet.

Comment: is that not the same as using my mkII? I am sure it's not the programmer because I used it a week ago to rip some firmware off another device which ended up being in tact. I thought I killed the adc.

Comment: What error do you get when trying to enter programming mode?  New chips should default to internal oscillator, but your MKII shouldn't have a problem with that.  The bigger problem is setting the chip to use an external oscillator when you don't have one available.  Is your programmer able to read the voltage correctly?

Comment: yes it says 4.7v. It says it "recived 0xc0 expected 0x00. command failed to execute on tool". I have verified the programmer is working on a mega connected to my cnc. The nano clone has a 3 pin smd oscillator. Reasonator? I never known crystals to have 3 pins.

Comment: ok, any chance you have the reset or SPI pins connected to something?  I see that same error if the reset pin or SPI pins are connected to another device that interferes with the external programmer.

Comment: no. I'm getting desperate. I even tried removing the oscillator. To try emulate a "virgin" chip. I dont know maybe it is fried. I give up the angry pixies are in a particularly bad mood.

Comment: One final idea you might try, slow down the clock on the MKII.  And just to double-check, the board is powered independently, correct?  The 4.7v reported may be from the USB powering the MKII, but it will fail to enter programming mode unless you are powering the chip separately.

Comment: Are you powering the Board? MKii does not provide power, it only monitors the voltage level being used.  Also, use a meter and buzz each pair of pins, make sure none are shorted together.

Answer (score -1):

You have probably got the "divide clock by 8" fuse set (that is the default). I have a [bootloader uploader](http://gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11635) sketch that you can run on another Arduino that should upload the bootloader, and the first thing it does is fix up that fuse bit. You don't need to remove the oscillator. The default is to not use it, but it doesn't hurt to have it in circuit.